# EXTJS 4 Gauge Chart Tool Tip not working?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

i am using EXTJS 4 Gauge Chart. and i want to display extjs4 charts tool tip.
but tool tip is not working in extjs Gauge Chart.

Thanks & Regards,
Gauravp

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a reported issue in ExtJS 4.0.6 and earlier. [See here for details on the sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?147315-4.0.6-Gauge-Chart-Does-not-Support-Tooltips-or-Mouse-Listeners)

The problem appears to be because the gauge chart does not implement isItemInPoint, it will never support highlighting or tips - isItemInPoint is used by the getItemForPoint function of a chart series to determine which item in the series is located at an x/y coordinate.

On the same sencha forum post a user "minneyar" has proposed a work-around for now by implementing the isItemInPoint method on the Gauge series prototype, here's the code for that:

```
Ext.chart.series.Gauge.override({
    isItemInPoint: function(x, y, item, i) {
        var chartBBox = this.chart.chartBBox;
        var centerX = this.centerX = chartBBox.x + (chartBBox.width / 2);
        var centerY = this.centerY = chartBBox.y + chartBBox.height;
        var outerRadius = Math.min(centerX - chartBBox.x, centerY - chartBBox.y);
        var innerRadius = outerRadius * +this.donut / 100;

        var r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(centerX-x, 2) + Math.pow(centerY-y,2));

        return r > innerRadius && r < outerRadius;
    }
});
```